# Is it possible to run a function after every PHPUnit test failure?

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using PHPUnit and Selenium 2 to do some integration tests on my web app. I would like a screenshot to be saved every time a test fails. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
include 'c:/wamp/www/testarea/selenium/phpunit-selenium/vendor/autoload.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{       
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.google.com/');
        file_put_contents("c:/wamp/www/testarea/selenium/phpunit-selenium/screenshots/screenshot1.png",$this->currentScreenshot());
        $this->assertEquals('NOT GOOGLE', $this->title());
    }

}
```

This works fine, and saves a screenshot when the test is run - however, I would like to be able to save a screenshot only after a test failure, and this should happen with every test. Is there a way of telling PHPUnit to automatically run a function after every test failure?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use the method `tearDown()` or `onNotSuccessfulTest()`

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Ricardo Simas's answer, if you do implement the onNotSuccessfulTest method, make sure you call parent, else the default *error* handling behaviour will stop happening.

I wondered why my tests were passing when there was clearly an error condition (element not found).

e.g. I've put this in an ancestor class for all my test cases:

```
public function onNotSuccessfulTest($e){
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/../../out/screenshots/screenshot1.png', $this->currentScreenshot());

    parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
}
```

Comment: How do you keep the browser session from closing before taking the screenshot in onNotSuccessfulTest($e)?

Comment: @darkrat It seems to do that automatically (possibly due to the parent call chain being after the screenshot?). Are you saying it is closing too soon for you, or were you just wondering?

Comment: I found that if I try and take the screenshot in onNotSuccessfulTest($e) that the browser has already closed and the screenshot capture throws an error.

However if I add the following in the tearDown() method I am able to get the screenshot  
    `if ($this->hasFailed()) {
            $file = $this->screenshot_dir . '/' . get_class($this) . '__' . $this->getName() . '__' . date('Y-m-d\TH-i-s') . '.png';
            file_put_contents($file,        $this->currentScreenshot());
            print "Screenshot captured at $file";
        }`

Comment: I wonder if it's a version difference? I'm using PHPUnit 4.8, but more importantly this is Selenium2 with the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase (as Selenium 1 does screenshots itself). I'm using the "last" Selenium 2 server 2.53.0

Comment: Another thought: is it a test failure, or an error? Perhaps it doesn't work on an error. My only phpunit.xml config is stopOnErrors=true. All else is defautl in this project.

Answer (score 0):

To run a function after each **Unsuccessful** test you can use:

```
onNotSuccessfulTest()    <- Runs after each failed test.
tearDown()               <- Runs after each test.
```

To run a function after each **successful** test you can use:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    if ($this->getStatus() == 0) {
        // stuff to do on sucsess
    } 
}
```